# Windows 7 on to Live USB Drive from OS X Virtual Box or IDO

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb-flash-drive, liveusb

I have a Windows 7 installation on VirtualBox and I'd like to boot it up from a BIOS computer using a USB stick.

Alternatively, I also have the Windows 7 ISO saved but UNetBootin's resultant USB drive did not boot- there was a black screen.

I also tried to dd the iso across to the USB drive- it didn't work.

What's the easiest/quickest way of me getting a live Windows 7 bootable USB drive?

Comment: Have you tried [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)?

Comment: @alljamin I've looked at it but the only copy of Windows that I have access to is in a VM and I can't get it to access my USB drive